# filling data to the ember controller without router

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I try fill ember controller without `setupController` hook, like this:

```
Ember.$.getJSON('http://url.com').then(function (response) {
 self.store.pushPayload('record', response);
 self.get('controllers.consultation').set('model', self.store.push('consultation', response.consultation));
});
```

Model for controller `consultation` contain hasMany field `records`

```
 export default DS.Model.extend({
        records: DS.hasMany('record', { async: true }),
        ....
    });
```

When I call `controller.records` in templates it's doesn't works (empty), but other fields works fine.

**Question:** why `controller.records` empty?

NOTE: When I create field in `consultation` controller which contain consultation object it's works.

```
self.get('controllers.consultation').set('controllerObj', self.get('controllers.consultation').set('model', self.store.push('consultation', response.consultation)));
```

Comment: You could try `{{model.records}}`, since you are setting `model` property in controller

Comment: `{{model.records}}` - really works, but I should call `{{controller.records}}` because controller consist compute property `records: function(){some logic}.property('model.records.@each'),`

Comment: if controller also has property `records` you could use `{{records}}` for them and `{{model.records}}` for `model.records`

Comment: `model.records.@each` might not work (i am not sure it works). see note at the end of page http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Comment: {{records}} like {{controller.records}} contains null. {{model.record}} works (not null) but not contain changes from controller .property('model.records.@each')

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to resolve `model.records` immediately after `model`.

```
var controller = this.get('controllers.consultation');
Ember.$.getJSON('http://url.com').then(function (response) {
   // ... your magic with store
   // var consultation = consultation instance extracted from response
   controller.set('model', consultation);
   return consultation.get('records'); // or your custom api request for model.records
}).then(function (records) {
   controller.set('modelRecords', records) // or your custom request records extraction
});
```

Then in controller you could set computed `records`:

```
// controller
records: function() {
  // your logic here
}.property('modelRecords.[]')
```

and `{{records}}` should work in template

```
//template
{{records.length}}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's could be working example, but `consultation` filling in `setupController` too and `.property('model.records.@each') is important `. I tried set records like this `controller.set('records', response.records);` bet get error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot set read-only property "records" on object:`

Comment: It's difficult to fix all issues without looking at completed code.